# Jquery change onchange in onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I edit this code so it runs on pageload and remove the `лв`? I want that the function runs on the onload event and not on the onchange event.

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="79.00лв" id="cenazatbi" name="cenazatbi"/ >
<div id="tbi">
    text
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#cena").change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() < 150) {
        $("#tbi").css("display", "none");
    }    
    else if ($(this).val() >150.01) {
        $("#tbi").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `document.ready` function will work on the page load

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
if ($(this).val().replace('лв') < 150) {
    $("#tbi").css("display", "none");
} else if ($(this).val().replace('лв') >150.01) {
     $("#tbi").css("display", "block");
}
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(document).ready` to execute functions when the dom is fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#cenazatbi').val(), 10);
    if (val < 150) {
        $("#tbi").css("display", "none");
    } else if (val > 150.01) {
        $("#tbi").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

the function `.parseInt()` will strip all non-digit characters of your value and cast the `string` into an `integer`.
As an alternative you can also use the `Number()`-function for this.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qur82um0/)

**Reference**

[.ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

[Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score 0):

Use $() for page load action:

```js
$(function() {
  var amt = $('#cenazatbi').val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''); // replace all other than digits and periods
  amt = +(amt); // parse to number, can also use parseFloat()
  $('#tbi').toggle(amt < 150.0); // hide if less than given amount
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="79.00лв" id="cenazatbi" name="cenazatbi" />
<div id="tbi">text</div>
```